# How to retrieve Barcode Value from a List

Tags: list, barcodes

we've activated barcode generation by enabling the barcode information management policy for items in a list and now want to get the value from the "barcode value" column. Unfortunately this column seems not to exist.
Does anybody knows how to get values from this column?
Here is the code i'm currently using

```
private void Test() {

        string Service_siteurl= "https://siteurl";
        string Service_userName= "user";
        string Service_passWord = "password";

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(Service_siteurl);
        SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
        Service_passWord.ToList().ForEach(secureString.AppendChar);
        ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Service_userName, secureString);
        List tickets = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Voranmeldungen");
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View>" +
            "                   <Query>" +
            "                       <Where>" +
            "                               <Eq>" +
            "                                   <FieldRef Name='Barcode Value' />" +
            "                                       <Value Type='Number'>978374995</Value>" +
            "                               </Eq>" +
            "                       </Where>" +
            "                   </Query>" +
            "               </View>";

        camlQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
        ListItemCollection items = tickets.GetItems(camlQuery);
        ctx.Load(items);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        if (items.Count > 0) {
            foreach (ListItem listItem in items) {
                outToLog("LISTITEM: " + listItem["Barcode Value"].ToString());
            }
        }
        else
            outToLog("No items....");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we read SharePoint field value programatically, we must use `Internal Name` of the column instead of `Display Name` of the column

You are using wrong internal name for the column i.e. `Barcode Value`. Correct Internal name of the column is `_dlc_BarcodeValue`. See below screen shot:

[image]

Try below code and it should work:

```
    string Service_siteurl = "https://siteurl";
    string Service_userName = "user";
    string Service_passWord = "password";

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(Service_siteurl);
    SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
    Service_passWord.ToList().ForEach(secureString.AppendChar);
    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Service_userName, secureString);
    List tickets = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Voranmeldungen");
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View>" +
        "                   <Query>" +
        "                       <Where>" +
        "                               <Eq>" +
        "                                   <FieldRef Name='_dlc_BarcodeValue' />" +
        "                                       <Value Type='Number'>978374995</Value>" +
        "                               </Eq>" +
        "                       </Where>" +
        "                   </Query>" +
        "               </View>";

    camlQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
    ListItemCollection items = tickets.GetItems(camlQuery);
    ctx.Load(items);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    if (items.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
        {
            outToLog("LISTITEM: " + listItem["_dlc_BarcodeValue"].ToString());
        }
    }
    else
        outToLog("No items....");
```

By the way according your code, it does not make sense to assign `ViewXml` to `camlQuery` object because at the end you are generating CAML Query to get all items using `CreateAllItemsQuery` method.

Below are some links which can help you to find out internal name of the SharePoint Column:

- https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2021/01/get-field-internal-name-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html
- https://github.com/bramdejager/spcb